# Update volume phase function

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shader-nodes, volumetrics, source-code

I have a Blender environment setup with a `Mix Shader` combining `Volume Absorption` and `Principled Volume` nodes to render a volume in the `Cycles` render engine. I am trying to change the volume `Henyey Greenstein` phase function for experiments.
In the source code, this corresponds to the `single_peaked_henyey_greenstein()` function in volume.h: https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/blender-v4.0-release/intern/cycles/kernel/closure/volume.h

But I also need to add a parameter in addition to the anisotropy g.

What is the best approach for this? So that I can also change the additional parameters in the shader editor

Comment: Are you asking how to change the source code or how to do this within Blender? Because this site is to help with issues using Blender, we are just users, no developers and not part of the Blender foundation. So for questions about the source code you are most likely in the wrong place here. For the shader setup: is there a special reason you are using a _Volume Absorption_ together with the _Principled Volume_? Why not use the _Absorption_ there? Or, if you want to control volume scattering and absorption separately, why not use a _Volume Scatter_ mixed/added with the _Volume Absorption_?

Comment: Yes you are right @GordonBrinkmann I should use _Volume Scatter_ together with _Volume Absorption_. Then regarding my question, if it is possible to modify the phase function within Blender then I choose this way, otherwise modify the code source. But I have no idea if this is possible.